# Show that $f(x) $ has either exactly 4 intersection points or either of the $3$ points is local maximum or miniumu.

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$, where  $a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{R}$

If it is given that $f(x)$ has at least $3$ intersection points on the $x-$ axis, then prove that $f(x) $ has either exactly 4 intersection points or either of the $3$ points is local maximum or miniumum.

I don't even understand what this problem is about, never mind attempting it.

Comment: ISI entrance exam question??!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If a fourth degree polynomial has exactly three intersections with the $X$ axis, it must have exactly one double root. What does that imply for the derivative conditions for extrema?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me verify my mistake that I posted in the question. Sorry!
It is not exactly 3 intersection points , but atleast.

Comment: So it has either exactly $4$ real roots or exactly $3$ real roots (without counting multiplicity).  In the latter case, one of the roots must have multiplicity $2$, and then the derivative at that root is _____.

Comment: Yeah that I get, but then how does it prove if the double roots is a local maxima or minima?

Comment: Once you have the form $f(x) = k(x-p)^2(x-q)(x-r)$, you should be able to show that $f'(p) = 0$ and $f''(p) \neq 0$.  Which shows it is either a local maximum or minimum. Work it out...

Comment: Okay I think I get it. Google tells me that second derivate test tell us if $f''(x=p)<0$ then it is minimum and vice versa. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $f(a)=f(b)$ then there exist $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c)=0$ and you know that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=f(x_3)=0$...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle's_theorem