# $3$ intersection points for a quartic polynomial implies 4 intersection points or a local extrema at one of the intersection points

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, proof-verification

**Q:** It is given that the graph of $y = x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ (where $a,b,c,d$
are real) has at least $3$ points of intersection with the $x$-axis. Prove
that either there are exactly $4$ distinct points of intersection, or one of
those $3$ points of intersection is a local minimum or maximum.

**My solution:**

Let $y=x^4+ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)(x-s)$ where $p,q,r\in\Bbb R$ are distinct ($3$ intersection points) and $s\in\Bbb C$ by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Now, by Vieta's formulas, we have $a=-(p+q+r+s)$ and since $a,p,q,r\in\Bbb R$, we must have $s\in\Bbb R$ since otherwise $a$ cannot be real.

In case $s$ is a real distinct from $p,q,r$, we conclude that there are $4$ distinct points of intersection.

In case $s$ is a real equal to one of $p,q,r$, say WLOG $s=p$, we have,

$$y=f(x)=(x-p)^2(x-q)(x-r)$$

Using chain rule, we can calculate $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ and we get $f'(p)=0$ and $f''(p)=2(p-q)(p-r)\neq 0$ since $p,q,r$ are distinct.

Since $f(p)=f'(p)=0$ and $f''(p)\neq 0$, by the second derivative test, we conclude that $x=s=p$ is a point of local minimum/maximum, i.e., one of the $3$ points of intersection is a local minimum or maximum.

And we're done.

---

Is the above proof correct / rigorous enough?

---

I noticed just now that this question has been [asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790505/show-that-fx-has-either-exactly-4-intersection-points-or-either-of-the-3) but there's no complete solution posted on it and so I think this question isn't a duplicate of it.

Comment: Since a real polynomial has complex conjugated roots, you don't need to prove that s is real through such articulated means. Also, WLOG=??

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando, yes, I had thought of using that argument but then I thought I'd need to prove the statement "a real polynomial has complex conjugated roots" itself as a lemma, hence I used a different argument. As for your question, WLOG means [without loss of generality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality). I used that term since we could've also taken $s=q$ or $s=r$ and we would've gotten the same conclusion through a similar argument.

Comment: Aah, yes. English is not my strongest language. Also, wow, I thought you could afford to assume that.